# RTSP Stream works in VLC but not my VideoView

Tags: android, streaming, vlc, rtsp

I am trying to stream to my Android Application from an IP Webcam over RTSP, the stream plays successfully via the VLC Android app, but I cannot replicate this in my own application.

```
if (mediaControls == null) 
{
    mediaControls = new MediaController(VideoActivity.this);
}

myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.stream);
myVideoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoActivity.this);
progressDialog.setTitle("Camera Stream");
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
//progressDialog.show();

try 
{
    myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
    myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoSrc));
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() 
{
    // Close the progress bar and play the video
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
    {
        //progressDialog.dismiss();
        myVideoView.seekTo(position);

        if (position == 0) 
        {
            myVideoView.start();
        } 
        else 
        {
            myVideoView.pause();
        }
    }
});
```

The activity prompts a "Cannot Play This Video" dialog. According to the Desktop VLC client the stream is MJPG, 320x256, displaying at 320x240, in the decoded format "Planar 4:2:0 YUV full scale." According to the camera's data sheet it is at 30fps.

I have been able to play other RTSP streams with this code, but not the one I need.

I have been trying to figure out how to use [libVLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/) but haven't had much luck so far. Can anyone help me to get this stream into something my application can use?

Comment: Motion JPEG isn't one of [the listed supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

Comment: I am able to view it in the VLC Android application. According to the camera's datasheet the stream should be 
"30fps @ 320x240 H.264/MJPEG(without
RAW) compression video through IP
Network"

Comment: "I am able to view it in the VLC Android application" -- yes, but they have their own media engine AFAIK, which is why they can handle a lot of stuff that ordinary Android apps can't.

Comment: Then do you think this is not possible? The camera's datasheet also mentions H.264, which I know is compatible

Comment: I don't know enough about H.264 to know if H.264 AVC (which is what [the page that I linked to](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) cites) is somehow compatible with H.264 MJPEG.

Comment: H.264 AVC and MJPEG are different methods of encoding and compressing video - i.e. you camera probably supports one or the other at a given time rather than some combination of the two. If you can get your output in H.264 encoding then that should playback in the standard MediaPlayer (only 'should' because video is a minefield of options and implementation differences so you probably still need to test to be sure).